# posting the value from a DDL back to code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dictionary, model-view-controller, ddl

MVC Using an exmaple I found online I have populated a dictionary and passed it to the view. I can view the drop down list and select different values. But my Q is how can I call a function in code behind with the new value selected posted back to code behind?

```
  //controller
     toolTipsVM.ListOfMaps = GetMapIds();

     public Dictionary<int, string> GetMapIds()
            {
                //List<int, string> mapIds = new List<int, string>();
                Dictionary<int, string> mapIds = new Dictionary<int, string>();
                mapIds.Add(36, "hi");
                mapIds.Add(37, "how");
                mapIds.Add(39, "now");

                return mapIds;
            }

    //VW
     public Dictionary<int, string> ListOfMaps { get; set; }

//View

     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MapId, new SelectList(Model.ListOfMaps, "Key", "Value"),
                                            "--Choose Map--",
                                                new {@class = "form-control"}
                                        )
```

Comment: There is no _in code behind_ in MVC. Do you have a form? Are you wanting to make an ajax call? What is your POST method?

Comment: Make a comma based array and send them to controller through ajax request in c#. It's the easiest way to get the data from view to controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you need to write function in Controller to pass the value.

   ```
   [Post]
   Post_MethodName(string Id)
   {
   }
   ```
2. Use following jQuery Ajax call to post the value to that function.

   ```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Controller/Post_MethodName", // the method we are calling
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {id: SelctedValue},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert('Success');
        ;                    
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Failed');
        }
    });
   ```
3. Use following function to get drop down list value

   ```
    $("#dropdownlistid option:selected").text();
   ```